# Is there a way to fix HTTP error 403 when webscraping ESPN's NBA data?

Tags: r, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I am trying to webscrape data from [this](https://www.espn.com/nba/team/schedule/_/name/bos/season/2021) website, but for every NBA team.

However, when I run the following code, I keep getting an HTTP error 403, specifically,

> "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403.

" I am at a loss at how to fix this since I have seen other projects webscrape the same exact site without any problems, using the same exact code.

```
library(rvest)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(zoo)
library(h2o)
library(lubridate)



teams<-c("tor", "mil", "den", "gs", "ind", "phi", "okc", "por", "bos", "hou", "lac", "sa",
         "lal", "utah", "mia", "sac", "min", "bkn", "dal", "no", "cha", "mem", "det", "orl",
         "wsh", "atl", "phx", "ny", "chi", "cle")

teams_fullname<-c("Toronto", "Milwaukee", "Denver", "Golden State", "Indiana", "Philadelphia", "Oklahoma City","Portland",
                  "Boston", "Houston", "LA", "San Antonio", "Los Angeles", "Utah", "Miami", "Sacramento", "Minnesota", "Brooklyn",
                  "Dallas", "New Orleans", "Charlotte", "Memphis", "Detroit", "Orlando", "Washington", "Atlanta", "Phoenix",
                  "New York", "Chicago", "Cleveland")

by_team<-{}
for (i in 1:length(teams)) {
  url<-paste0("http://www.espn.com/nba/team/schedule/_/name/", teams[i])
  #print(url)
  webpage <- read_html(url)
  team_table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
  team_c <- html_table(team_table, fill=TRUE, header = TRUE)[[1]]
  team_c<-team_c[1:which(team_c$RESULT=="TIME")-1,]
  team_c$URLTeam<-toupper(teams[i])
  team_c$FullURLTeam<-(teams_fullname[i])
  by_team<-rbind(by_team, team_c)
}

# remove the postponed games
by_team<-by_team%>%filter(RESULT!='Postponed')
```

I am simply wondering why this is happening and/or how to fix this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fewer and fewer sites are allowing direct rvest::read_html(url).
Use httr::GET(url) or httr::RETRY('GET', url) first. (R>=4.1 for new pipe)

```
webpage <- url |>
  httr::GET() |>
  rvest::read_html()
```